# Image added to UITableViewCell appears in wrong rows when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm adding an image to a table view row (actually, I seem to be adding it to the row's cell) when selecting it (and removing when selecting it again). The table view consists of prototype cells.

This works but when I scroll around and get back to the row I had previously selected, the image would be in another row. Also, the image appears in other rows as well.

My guess is this happens because the cells are re-used when scrolling.
 Here's the code of a little sample project:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  // Using integers for simplicity, should work with strings, too.
  var numbers = [Int]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0..<50 {
      numbers.append(i)
    }
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(numbers[indexPath.row] + 1)"

    return cell
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numbers.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    if let myImage = curCell.viewWithTag(10) as? MyImage {
      myImage.removeFromSuperview()
    } else {
      let myImage = myImage()
      myImage.tag = 10
      cell.addSubview(myImage)
    }

  }
```

I need to have the image stay in the correct row, also when coming back to this view controller. What's the correct way to tackle this?
Any advice much appreciated!

**EDIT**: I've tried to implement matt's answer but I seem to be missing something, as the problem is still the same.

**EDIT 2**: Updated, working as intended now.

```
import UIKit

class ListItem {

  var name: String!
  var showsImage = false

  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }

}


class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var listItems = [ListItem]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0..<50 {
      let listItem = ListItem(name: "row \(i)")
      listItems.append(listItem)
    }
  }


  // MARK: - Table view data source

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(listItems[indexPath.row].name)"

    if listItems[indexPath.row].showsImage {
      let myImage = myImage
      myImage.tag = 10
      cell.addSubview(myImage)
    } else {
      if let myImage = cell.viewWithTag(10) as? myImage {
      myImage.removeFromSuperview()
      listItems[indexPath.row].showsImage = false
    }

    return cell
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listItems.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    if let myImage = cell.viewWithTag(10) as? myImage {
      myImage.removeFromSuperview()
      listItems[indexPath.row].showsImage = false
    } else {
      listItems[indexPath.row].showsImage = true
      tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
    }
  }

}
```

**EDIT 3**: As matt suggested, here's an alternative solution to the code above which subclasses UITableViewCell instead of using a tag for the image.

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  var myImage = MyImage()

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    myImage.hidden = true
    addSubview(myImage)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

}


class ListItem {

  var name: String!
  var showsImage = false

  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }

}

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var listItems = [ListItem]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0..<50 {
      let listItem = ListItem(name: "row \(i)")
      listItems.append(listItem)
    }
  }


  // MARK: - Table view data source

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listItems.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = MyTableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "TestCell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(listItems[indexPath.row].name)"
    cell.myImage.hidden = !(listItems[indexPath.row].showsImage)

    return cell
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    listItems[indexPath.row].showsImage = cell.myImage.hidden
    cell.myImage.hidden = !cell.myImage.hidden
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that cells are reused in other rows. When they are, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called again. But when it is, you are supplying no information about the image for that row.

The solution: fix your *model* (i.e. the info you consult in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) so that it knows about the image. In `didSelect`, do not modify the cell directly. Instead, modify the *model* and reload the cell.

Comment: Hi matt, thanks a lot for your help. I've tried to implement your answer and added the code example to my post. I'm still doing something wrong, it would be great if you could have a quick look at it. Thank you!

Comment: Very nice! You're almost there. You've simply made a tiny logic error. Your `cellForRow` has this condition: `if listItems[indexPath.row].showsImage`, but you have forgotten to say what should happen _otherwise_. You need to add an `else` clause that _removes_ the image. At that point, I think everything will start to fall into place. In other words, remember that `cellForRow` must _completely_ configure each cell, because you never know whether the cell is being reused. — Also, watch out, you are now likely to add multiple image views to the same cell repeatedly. Think about it...!

Comment: Thank again! I've updated the code. Indeed, it seems to work now! EDIT: I've just read your post again, would I need to subclass UITableViewCell (I'd like to avoid, if possible) and add the image as a property that I hide and show, instead of adding it each time?

Comment: The solution if you don't want to subclass is exactly what you're doing, namely to give the image view a `tag` so that you can locate it again easily later. I have a weird sense that this approach may be discouraged by Apple in future but at present it is totally legal. Still, I have to ask: what is the objection to subclassing? This would take just a couple of new lines of code — you don't even need a new file, you can do it right in the MyTableViewController file — and a tiny change in the storyboard stating the class of the prototype cell.

Comment: There really isn't much of a legit reason why I wouldn't want to subclass. I think I just like working with the original classes whenever possible. However, after rewriting the code as you suggested, it's much more condensed that way. Please have a look and let me know if there's something to improve. Again, thanks a lot for helping out, much appreciated!

Comment: All I can tell you is that I can read the code at a glance and it is completely transparent as to what it does. Can't ask more than that! Pls note that you can rewrite this line `cell.myImage.hidden = listItems[indexPath.row].showsImage ? false : true` more compactly and (I think) clearly as `cell.myImage.hidden = !(listItems[indexPath.row].showsImage)`. You could even get rid of the `!` by reversing the sense of `showsImage` and calling it `hidesImage`. :)

Comment: Ok, I´ve updated the code example, thanks for being so patient; I´ve certainly learned a few things here! Wish I could give more upvotes!

Comment: Also, I kept `showsImage`, so I could change `listItems[indexPath.row].showsImage = cell.myImage.hidden ? true : false` to `listItems[indexPath.row].showsImage = cell.myImage.hidden` :D